# How to redirect https domain to http domain using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

How can I redirect

```
https://domain.com
```

to

```
http://newdomain.com
```

using htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
```